# How to change primaryStage css during runtime (using a code in another class) in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, themes, desktop-application

I'm building a JavaFX app. I implemented a dark mode, but it requires restart to apply theme changes since I cannot reach primaryStage from anywhere but start method. How can I reach it and update the style sheets. Or what other method can I use to approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javafx change css at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769388/javafx-change-css-at-runtime)

Comment: No, I have a Settings class in which I have a toggle for changing the theme. I cannot just simply change the css of the scene of the primaryStage from outside the public void start method. That's the problem.